# Wrong (Date) date return in Java

Tags: java, date

I have the following line in my code:

```
this.date = new Date(year, month, day);
```

But when I give, for example:

```
year = 2008
month = 1
day = 20
```

I get:

```
Thu Feb 20 00:00:00 BRT 3908
```

Or let's say:

```
year = 2008
month = 3
day = 9
```

I get:

```
Thu Apr 09 00:00:00 BRT 3908
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. It does exactly what it's supposed to. Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: The constructor Date(int year, int month, int date) is deprecated, you should use Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) instead.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but the teacher said I can only use Date... I don't know why... Anyway, the problem is solved, I'll mark the answer soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29) about the constructor. The parameters are not simply what you think they are.

It says:

> `year` - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
>   `month` - 0 to 11
>   `day` - 1 to 31

However, as the Docs say as well, it is deprecated. Construct dates using a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead. Or use JodaTime.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe that it was that easy. `this.date = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day);`

Comment: And about Calendar: Yeah, I know that, but the teacher said I can only use Date... I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

The month is zero-based. So 0 is Jan and 1 is Feb, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Date date= new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said correctly, you assumed month numbers were 1-based counting. But in fact they are 0-based counting. One of the many problems with the java.util.Date/Calendar classes.

As a workaround, use the pre-defined constants rather than try to remember that ridiculous numbering scheme:

- [java.util.Calendar.JANUARY](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY)
- java.util.Calendar.FEBRUARY
- …
- java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER

Better yet, get a real date-time framework: either (a) [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or (b) the similar and new [JSR 310: Date and Time API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) bundled in Java 8 to supplant java.util.Date/Calendar.